# How to check particular cell is updated in JTable using Java?

Tags: jtable

I have a jtable in which 15 rows and 15 columns.From database,populating the value into table.While saving back,need to update into database.Everytime, if any changes happen,user needs to update the value by clicking update button.So now I am updating whole vaues in db,whenever update is clicked.
But is there any way to check particular cell is updated ,i need to update that value only instead of updating whole vaues.?
Please anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add action listener to row(More on that [here](http://forums.devx.com/archive/index.php/t-27297.html)). When updated, get the row's unique id, add it to some list. When you want to update to database, update only those that are in the list. Hope that helps.

Comment: There is no action listener for JTable.How to add the action listener to row?

Comment: There's a link in my answer. http://forums.devx.com/archive/index.php/t-27297.html